# The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2371 in the message file for Application. on Win Server 2012 R2 using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, set, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a batch file that works fine on Win7 64bit but not on Windows Server 2012 R2.
I simplified the file to this:

```
@echo off
echo drag and drop your file here
set /p file= %~1
echo file name: %file%
pause
```

As soon as I start the .bat, just after the echo, I get the following error:

> The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2371 in the
>   message file for Application.

It seems it's the set command that doesn't work properly. I tried to run the bat file from ´C:\Windows\System32´ but get the same error.

Thanks

Comment: What is the intent of this script? `%~1` would be the first parameter passed to your script, so why are you prompting the user with this value?

Comment: I'm asking the user to drag&drop a file into the CMD window. `%~1` contains the name/path of the file. I also tried to replace `%~1` by some random text but the same error is displayed.

Comment: You don't need the `%~1`. Try updating to just `set /p file=`

Comment: Also, check the encoding/line break type used in your batch text file. If in doubt, just copy/paste the whole thing to Notepad.

Comment: I tried `set /p file=` and copy/paste in Notepad, same problem.

Comment: I tried on a server 2012 machine and had no issue with what you posted above.

Comment: Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: How did you started the command prompt? I have the same problem only when I start the command prompt by typing cmd in the addres bar in a folder.

Comment: I ran into this problem today.  My issue was due to the cmd.exe opened.  When typing cmd in my search, it opened C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_c2d5dc8a656fefd1\cmd.exe.  When I opened C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe, performing set /p worked as expected.